# parameterized ellipse, error in proof of a theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

A question from the book "Elementary Differential Geometry" from A Pressley

> Consider the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{p^2}+\frac{y^2}{q^2}=1$, where $p>q>0$
>   The eccentricity of the ellipse is $\epsilon = \sqrt{1-\frac{q^2}{p^2}}$ and the points $(\pm\epsilon, 0)$ are called the foci of the ellipse, which are denoted by $\bf F_1, F_2$. Verify that $\mathbf{c}(t) = (p\cos(t), q\sin(t))$ is a parameterization of the ellipse.
>
> Prove that:
>
> b) The product of the distances from $\bf F_1, F_2$ to the tangent line at any point $\bf P$ on the ellipse does not depend on $\bf P$.

I've tried to prove this as following:

### Proof

Take a certain $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{c}(t)$.
We calculate $\mathbf{\dot{c}}(t) = (-p\sin(t), q\cos(t))$ and $||\mathbf{\dot{c}}(t)|| = \sqrt{p^2\sin^2(t)+q^2\cos^2(t)}$

1. We calculate the distance from $F_1$ to the tangent line. 
   First lets calculate $\mathbf{PF_1} = \mathbf{F_1}-\mathbf{P} = [p(\epsilon-\cos(t)), -q\sin(t)]$

   Then, we calculate $\mathbf{\dot{c}}(t)\times \mathbf{PF_1}$ using the determinant calculation this is equal to $[0,0,pq(1-\epsilon\cos(t)]$

   So the distance from $\bf F_1$ to the tangent line is $\frac{||\mathbf{\dot{c}}(t)\times \mathbf{PF_1}||}{||\mathbf{\dot{c}}(t)||} = \frac{pq|1-\epsilon \cos (t)|}{\sqrt{p^2\sin^2(t)+q^2\cos^2(t)}}$
2. I calculate the same for the distance of $\bf F_2$ to the tangent line.

   I have found: $\frac{pq|1+\epsilon \cos (t)|}{\sqrt{p^2\sin^2(t)+q^2\cos^2(t)}}$
3. To multiply these distances:

$$=\frac{p^2 q^2 |1-\epsilon^2 \cos^2|}{p^2q^2 \left(\sin^2(t) + \frac{q^2}{p^2}\cos^2(t)\right)}$$

Substituting the $\epsilon$ in the numerator, and above results in $=1$.

QED?

### Problem ?

I was happy with the above, however when i was checking it with Geogebra i got the following. And the product of the distances cleary isn't equal to one... Where s the error?
[image: Geogebra picture of the situation]

Comment: Ooops, typo! Just a second, i'll edit the question...

Comment: Because the theorem I wrote was wrong, the theorem states that the product of the distances from the foci to the tangent line is independent of $\mathbf{P}$. The GeoGebra drawing confirms this. For any valid $p$ and $q$ this is true. But when $p=2.3$ and $q=1.4$ the product of distances $=1.96$ and not $1$ as I 'proved', how come?

Comment: @DanielFischer, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my calculations once more revealed a tiny error near the end. It should have been

$$=\frac{p^2 q^2 |1-\epsilon^2 \cos^2|}{p^2\left(\sin^2(t) + \frac{q^2}{p^2}\cos^2(t)\right)} = q^2$$

Instead of 1. And this is confirmed by GeoGebra :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this because somebody posted about it on Reddit [reddit homework help question](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeworkHelp/comments/440p2o/intro_to_differential_geometry_university_proof/). I recently joined StackExchange, so I thought that I would post an answer here even though your question is a year old.

I think the error is in step 3: in the denominator, you have taken a factor of $p^2$, but you have written $p^2q^2$. With the value for q in the image, this explains why you got 1 and the answer was $1.96 = 1.4^2$.